# AutoMapper: ignore property on update existing, but allow when create

Tags: c#, automapper

Is it possible to configure/use AutoMapper in such a way where when i **create** an object from a mapping i allow all properties and child collections, however, when it comes to performing an **update** to existing object, the mapping will ignore child collection properties as they will be empty but i dont want them removed.

This is because i am working with a WCF service that sends delta changes to objects and most of my model works in a tree hierarchy:

```
Parent
  List<Child> Children

ParentDto
  List<ChildDto> Children

config.CreateMap<ParentDto, Parent>();
config.CreateMap<ChildDto, ChildDto>();
```

This works well and the child collection is populated first time round. However, there are scenarios where i will send the ParentDto across with just the parent POCO property changes (such as a datetime change), but the child list will be empty as none of them have changed. Normally i would do:

```
_Mapper.Map<ParentDto,Parent>(dto, local)
```

but obviously that will change the entire tree and populate the local object with an empty child list. Massively simplifying but would something like

```
_Mapper.Map<ParentDto, Parent>(dto, local).Ignore(p => p.Children)
```

be possible?

I should also add I am using SimpleInjector DI framework. So perhaps there is a way to register 2 configurations, one with ignore and one without?

Answer (score 2):

Use `.ForMember(dest => dest.A, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.B))` for mapping only properties you need to update.

Comment: thanks; how would i use that in the scenario i outlined above? I need full tree when creating initial object, but ignore child collections when updating existing.

Answer (score 0):

For those who still struggle to find this. You can use [Autommapper Conditional Mapping](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Conditional-mapping).

You can do it like this, in the Initialize

```
config.CreateMap<ChildDto, ChildDto>().ForMember(dest => dest.Children, opt => opt.Condition(source => source.TriggerChildMap));
```

This will ignore mapping based on the property in source object. To map against existing destination you need to use 
`Mapper.Map(source, destination)` method and not the `var result = Mapper.Map<ChildDto>(source)` property.